# wp7, How to block scrolling in ScrollViewer

Tags: locking, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I wont to move UIElements in ScrollViewer. I have somthink like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll">
    <Canvas x:Name="sheet" Width="480" Height="10000">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="51" Canvas.Top="116" Height="114" Width="337"/>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I move the rectangle using ManipulationDelta event. However when I do it the scrollViewer scrolls as well.

How to lock scrolling of ScrollViewer?

that code doesn't help at all.

```
ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

I've lost 3 days to find solution and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just in on dealing with gesture conflict on pano / pivot.

[Preventing the Pivot or Panorama controls from scrolling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/luc/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed:%20msdn/VbhA%20%28MSDN%20Blogs%29)

Comment: Great :).. let us know if anything else is needed to Answer the question.