# How to stop ScrollViewer from Scrolling for Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have the following XAML :

<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,226,0,0" Name="Scv" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

<Canvas Height="100" Name="canvas1" Width="292" >
   Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="440" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="730" / >
     <InkPresenter Name="inkPresenter1"></InkPresenter>
     </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>

The problem : How do I stop the ScrollViewer from scrolling AFTER i have scrolled the image to the point I wanted.

In the Above example, I use scrollViewer to scroll the image to a section where I want to stop so that I can use InkPresenter to draw. But Whenever I draw Up or down, the scrollviewer follows the action of InkPresenter Up and down movement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check this discussion:
[How to block scrolling in ScrollViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244520/wp7-how-to-block-scrolling-in-scrollviewer)

Another option could be to dynamically set the SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility do Disabled:

```
ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(scrollViewer, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```

Comment: @BMiloshevka: Thank. NOt Working. As I have a button which I used to scroll with this :Scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sc.VerticalOffset);